# Why doesn't collapsing duplicate rows work for me?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to filter out duplicate rows in my excel sheet

[image]

By selecting column B and checking unique records only I expect this to collapse to a single row, but this isnt happening. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Change B2:B3 to B1:B3. The header must be selected too. Just tested it with Excel 2013, don't know if they changed something there since you are using Excel 2007 (?)

Comment: 2010. And thats weird... I just selected column B and it defaulted to b2:b3

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in the comments, Advanced Filters require a header. Your current setup defaults the top row to a header and therefore doesn't compare the data to it while checking for duplicates. You need to expand your filter *list range* to include the header e.g. `B:B` or `$B$1:$B$3`.